# jQuery animation only working in IE - 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, compatibility

I have a very simple animation, were I have a tab at the side of the screen and if you click it, it will increase size. But it´s only working on IE, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#a-tab,#a-tab > *")
        .on('focusin', function () {
        $("#a-tab").animate({
            width: '320px'}, "fast");
        $(".deluxe").animate({
            width: '30px'}, "slow");
    })
        .on('focusout', function () {
        $("#a-tab").animate({
            width: '10px'}, "fast");
        $(".deluxe").animate({
             width: '5px'}, "fast");
    });
});
```

It has to be `#a-tab > *` because of the inside content

Were is the problem, how can I make it compatible with Chrome, Firefox, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/dadVt/

THIS is a repost, because I don't know how to get fast help in another way, If you know how just let me know. (added the full code)

page - http://claudiacabrera.cl/flores.html

Comment: You don't have any elements that can have focus.

Comment: IE2!? How many versions do you test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that not all elements are focusable, `DIV` elements being one.

A workaround is to add the attribute `tabindex` to your element. This allows the element to receive focus (clicking), or by tabbing to the element.

Now your `focusin` and `focusout` event handlers will be triggered. Unfortunately, you'll need to trigger the focusout event (clicking the body, for instance? Or calling `focus()` on another element) so your tab closes.

Here's an updated fiddle (with jQuery included)

http://jsfiddle.net/dadVt/1/

Comment: how can I make the picture of the g+ thing also "selectable" by the browser?